# Set card height same for all cards used in owl-carousel

Tags: html, css

I use cards for images in my carousel, and I'd like to make the height of each card equivalent.
Using the class `h-100` doesn't work.

Changing any of the `p` tag content makes the size of the card different from the others whilst I'd like it to have a fixed size.

I'm looking forward to any tips and solutions you might come up with.
Thanks.

Below is my HTML code :

```html
     <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="related-carousel section-padding owl-carousel">
                  <div class="card_new h-100" style="">
                    <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <a href="video_info.php"><p class="card-text">..........................</p></a>
                    </div>
                   </div> 
                   <div class="card_new h-100" style="">
                    <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                     <a href=""><p class="card-text">..............................</p></a>
                    </div>
                   </div> 
                  <div class="card_new h-100" style="">
                    <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <a href=""><p class="card-text">.........................</p></a>
                    </div>
                   </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Add your css snipets too!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    .owl-carousel {display: flex;}
.card_new{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```